# Как я могу получить выделенные в текущий момент элементы из SelectedItems?

Tags: c#, wpf

Нужно из DataGrid получить выбранные в данный момент элементы.

Пытаюсь сделать так, но комманда вообще не вызывается:

```
  <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding DictionaryDataView}" ColumnWidth="*">
        <b:Interaction.Triggers>
            <b:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <b:InvokeCommandAction CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItems}" 
                                       Command="{Binding SelectedItemsCommand }" />
            </b:EventTrigger>
        </b:Interaction.Triggers>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Прибиндить `DataGrid.SelectedItem` к свойству типа данных, которые представляют одну строку таблицы, и в сеттере вызвать то, что вам нужно. Если вы используете `Interaction.Triggers` - это первый индикатор того, что вы что-то забыли изучить в WPF/XAML и пытаетесь воткнуть костыль. Штука конечно полезная, но в 99,(9)% случаев она используется разработчиками как костыль. Ваш случай - не исключение.

Comment: А, пардон, много выделенных строк? Ну тогда немного посложнее, но суть коммента выше остается неизменной. Нужно прибиндить `DataGridRow.IsSelected` к свойству типа `bool` во вьюмодели, представляющей строку таблицы. И далее в сеттере того же `SelectedItem` выбирать `Linq` запросом нужный список вьюмоделей. Или в команде по кнопке, где вам удобнее, там и запрашивайте.

Comment: `<DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle><DataTemplate><Style TagretType="DataGridRow"><Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding DataContext.Selected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/></Style></DataTemplate></DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>` как-то так, и завести во вьюмодели данных свойство `public bool Selected { ... }` Побочный эффект, если добавить `OnPropertyChanged` в свойство - будет возможность выделять строчки таблицы программно.

Comment: @aepot хм... А как быть если я бинжу DataTable? Т.е в своем классе я могу завести новое свойство под это дело, а как быть с DataTable?

Comment: Забрать данные из `DataTable` в коллекцию вьюмоделей? Сама DT не особо подходит на роль вьюмодели, она скорее просто модель.

Comment: @aepot может быть... Но если данные динамические и идут из БД, то DataTable дает весь необходимый функционал, а так нужно изобретать велосипед...

Comment: Ну, задача творческая, не спорю. Но из коробки я решений не припомню. Можно попробовать унаследоваться от `DataTable`, `DataRowCollection` и `DataRow`  и добавить своих свойств, штука не простая, но в теории возможная.